# Install a private package with credentials from requirements.txt

Tags: azure, databricks, credentials, requirements.txt, secrets

I want to a private package via

```
%pip install -r /dbfs/requirements.txt
```

Inside this requirements.txt is give:

```
git+https://<user>:$token@<gitprovider>.com/<path/to/repo>
```

If i give user and token inside the requirements.txt it works like a charm, but I want to pass user and token via dbutils.secrets. Is this doable without manipulating the requirements.txt before?

I thought it would be possible to create environment variables, but this did not work for me.

```
%env GIT_USERNAME= ...
%env GIT_TOKEN= ...
```

Comment: Did you considered using SSH keys and using ssh to access the repository? That way you could set up password-less login to your Git provider.

Answer (score 2):

The way is using python

1. Getting information
2. Store the information in a temporary file so that its details will not be found in the run log or records after running
3. Run

```
import dbutils

username = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="your_scope", key="git_username")
token = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="your_scope", key="git_token")

repo_url = f"git+https://{username}:{token}@gitprovider.com/path/to/repo"

requirements_path = "/dbfs/tmp/requirements.txt"

with open(requirements_path, "w") as file:
    file.write(repo_url + "\n")

dbutils.notebook.run("%pip install -r " + requirements_path, 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest way would be to use a `~/.netrc` file, that way you don't pollute your `requirements.txt` with usernames/passwords.

If you've never used a `~/.netrc` file, then `touch ~/.netrc` first, otherwise add this line (either programmatically or manually)

```
machine <gitprovider>.com login <user> password <token>
```

Now your requests should [pick up the authentication](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/) without you having to manually specify it, i.e. this is what your `requirement.txt` line is

```
git+https://<gitprovider>.com/<path/to/repo>
```

Note: If this is running in a pipeline, etc. you can also use a `~/.netrc`, and clear it up when the pipeline ends or rely on whatever sort of garbage collection exists.